# NASM on DOSBox - Program seemingly merges with another program

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16, dosbox

I'm having a weird problem with my ASM code launched in DOSBox. I wrote the following code:

```
      section  .text
      global   start
start:    
      ; Getting command line arguments
      xor      si, si
      xor      ax, ax
      mov      byte [st], 0
      mov      al, [ds:80h]             ; Getting arguments' string length
      mov      si, ax                   ; Storing in index register
      mov      byte [ds:81h+si], 0      ; Adding string termination symbol

      ; Opening file
      mov      dx, 82h                  ; Filename address
      mov      al, 0                    ; Read-only mode
      mov      ah, 3Dh                  ; Calling 3Dh interrupt
      int      21h
      jc       exit
      mov      bx, ax

  ; Calculating number of lines
      mov      cx, 0                    ; Zeroing counter
calclp:   lea      dx, [buf]                ; Getting buffer address
      mov      ah, 3Fh                  ; Calling read
      push     cx                       ; Storing counter
      mov      cx, 40                   ; Reading 40 bytes
      int      21h                      ; Calling interrupt
      cmp      ax, 0                    ; If ax = 0, no symbols were read -> EOF, exiting
      je       findlast
      add      dx, ax                   
      mov      bp, dx
      mov      byte [ds:bp], 0          ; Putting zero at the end of the string
      pop      cx                       ; Restoring cx
      xor      si, si                   ; Zeroing index
      lea      bp, [buf]                ; Getting buffer address
calcchlp: mov      dl, [bp+si]              ; Getting char from buffer
      inc      si
      cmp      dl, 0                    ; If zero - end of buffer
      je       calclp                   ; Reading another 40 bytes
      cmp      dl, 0Ah                  ; If newline - incrementing counter
      jne      calcchlp                 ; If not - continuing loop
      inc      cx
      jmp      calcchlp

findlast: pop      cx
      lea      bp, [ln]                 ; Saving the result
      mov      [bp], cx                 
      lea      bp, [lastb]              ; Zeroing lastb
      mov      word [bp], 0
      mov      word [bp+2], 0
      sub      cx, 0Fh                   
      cmp      cx, 0                    ; If number of lines =< 15, the first and the last 15 lines are the same
      jle      clear                    ; In that case, simply exiting, leaving lastb = 0

      mov      ah, 42h                  ; Resetting file pointer to the start of the file
      mov      al, 0h
      mov      cx, 0
      mov      dx, 0
      int      21h

flcalclp: lea      dx, [buf]                ; Getting buffer address
      mov      ah, 3Fh                  ; Calling read
      push     cx                       ; Storing line counter
      mov      cx, 40                   ; Reading 40 bytes
      int      21h                      ; Calling interrupt
      cmp      ax, 0                    ; If ax = 0, no symbols were read -> EOF, though we should not reach EOF here
      je       exit                     ; In that case, it's error - exiting
      add      dx, ax
      mov      bp, dx
      mov      byte [ds:bp], 0          ; Putting zero at the end of the string
      pop      cx                       ; Restoring cx
      xor      si, si                   ; Zeroing index
      lea      bp, [buf]                ; Getting buffer address
flchlp:   mov      dl, [bp+si]              ; Getting char from buffer
      inc      si
      cmp      dl, 0                    ; If zero - end of buffer
      je       flcalclp                 ; Reading another 40 bytes
      cmp      dl, 0Ah                  ; If newline - decrementing counter
      jne      flchlp                   ; If not - continuing loop
      dec      cx
      cmp      cx, 0                    ; If counter = 0, we reached 15th line from the end
      je       getlastb                 ; Jumping to finding actual byte number
      jmp      flchlp                    

      ; Calling seek to find the exact byte number
getlastb: mov      ah, 42h                  ; Seek call
      mov      al, 1h                   ; Seeking from the current position
      mov      cx, 0                    ; Offset = 0
      mov      dx, 0
      int      21h
      jc       exit
      lea      bp, [lastb]              ; DX:AX contains offset from the start, storing it
      mov      [bp], ax
      mov      [bp+2], dx              

      mov      ah, 42h                  ; Resetting file pointer to the start of the file
      mov      al, 0h
      mov      cx, 0
      mov      dx, 0
      int      21h   

      ; Clearing the screen
clear:    mov      al, 03h                  ; 80x25, 16 colors video mode
      mov      ah, 0h                   ; Enabling video mode
      int      10h

      ; Printing 15 lines
      mov      cx, 15                   ; Line counter for 15 lines 
printlp:  lea      dx, [buf]                ; Getting buffer address
      mov      ah, 3Fh                  ; Read function
      push     cx                       ; Saving cx
      mov      cx, 40                   ; Number of bytes to read
      int      21h                      ; Reading into buffer
      cmp      ax, 0
      je       keyproc
      add      dx, ax
      mov      bp, dx
      mov      byte [ds:bp], 0          ; Putting zero at the end of the string
      pop      cx                       ; Restoring cx
      xor      si, si                   ; Zeroing index
      lea      bp, [buf]                ; Getting buffer address
charlp:   mov      dl, [bp+si]              ; Getting char from buffer
      cmp      dl, 0                    ; Checking if symbol is zero 
      je       printlp                  ; If it is, reading another line
      cmp      dl, 0Ah                  ; Checking if symbol is newline
      jne      printch                  ; If it's not, jumpt to printing it
      dec      cx                       ; Decrementing line counter
      cmp      cx, 0                    ; Checking if counter = 0
      je       keyproc                  ; If it is, we printed all the lines, exit loop
printch:  mov      ah, 02h                  ; Calling stdout write
      int      21h
      inc      si                       ; Incrementing index
      jmp      charlp                   

keyproc:  mov      ah, 0                    ; Waiting for a key to be pressed
      int      16h
      cmp      al, 20h                  ; if space, swap state
      je       swap
      cmp      al, 71h                  ; if q, quit
      jne      keyproc
      mov      ax, 0                    ; exit code 0
      jmp      exit

swap:     cmp      byte [st], 0             ; Checking state variable
      je       toend                    ; If it's 0, jumping to the last 15 lines, otherwise to the first 
tostart:  mov      byte [st], 1             ; Swapping state
      mov      ah, 42h                  ; Calling seek file
      mov      al, 0                    ; From the beginning
      mov      cx, 0                    ; Offset is 0
      mov      dx, 0
      int      21h                      
      jc       exit                     ; If error - exit
      jmp      clear                    ; If not - clearing screen and printing text
toend:    mov      byte [st], 0             ; Swapping state
      mov      ah, 42h          
      mov      al, 0                    ; From the start
      lea      bp, [lastb] 
      mov      cx, [bp+16]              ; Offset was calculated before
      mov      dx, [bp]
      int      21h
      jc       exit
      jmp      clear 

exit:     mov      ah, 4Ch
      int      21h

      section  .bss
buf:      resb     40                       ; Text buffer
st:       resb     1                        ; State variable
ln:       resw     1                        ; Number of lines
lastb:    resd     1                        ; Number of the fist byte of the last 15 lines
```

Basically, I'm trying to calculate the number of lines in some file, and then quickly switch between displaying the first 15 and the last 15 lines of said file. However, while executing my code my program seems to merge with some other program, i.e. commands in my code are followed by some other commands completely alien to my code. Here's and example:
[image: my code on the left, disassembly result to the right]
My code is to the left, and the disassembler output is to the right. You can see that from `sub cx, 0Fh` the following commands are something else, and the rest of this code ends with `iret`, resulting in an endless loop.

I am using NASM version 2.12.01 and assemble executables for DOS via `nasm -f bin example.asm -o example.com`. I use DOSBox version 0.74 to execute assembled programs.

Comment: You forgot the `org 100h` to set your origin appropriate for a `.com` file so you are overwriting your own code.

Comment: @Jester yep, that was the case. Wasn't aware of this before.